# Where to copy referenced assemblies in a .NET project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a bunch of assemblies (DLLs) I want to reference in my current .NET 4.5 project. However, right now all of them sit in some local folder in my Hard Drive. When someone works on this same project, these reference assemblies obviously aren't in the same local folder. My plan is to copy these assemblies into some folder in my project, and put that in source control.

Is this a good plan? And what folder do these things usually go to?

Comment: Are those dependencies in NuGet packages? If so, you can exclude the binaries themselves but include the package configuration, and others will be able to fetch the packages automatically.

Comment: right click in visual studio and choose add reference or copy it in bin folder

Comment: To expand on @JonSkeet 's comment, if they _aren't_ in NuGet packages, I highly recommend _putting_ them in NuGet packages.  Starting to do this with my internal library assemblies has simplified my dependency management immensely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet is a prefer method; however, some assemblies are not in NuGet. So here is an example what nopCommerce does.

1. Create a Dependencies folder (inside your project folder)
2. Keeps all third parties assemblies inside it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a good idea. Generally I'll have a "dependencies" directory at the top level of the solution (or one higher if you have one), with all the DLLs that the projects use. Those are in source control, so when you check the code out, it will just work as-is, since the DLLs are all relative to the projects.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is the most common way to use external libraries and it places the dependencies in a folder called Packages at the root of the solution folder. You can create a folder called dependencies for your non-nuget dependencies. By placing this folder at the root of your solution you can make relative references so that works for everyone.

Answer (score -3):

Better way to GAC all the DLL assemblies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.80).aspx

```
gacutil -i "DLL File Path"
```

Comment: This would put the DLLs only on his machine. He wants the DLLs to be part of the project so anyone else working on it would have them referenced already byt the project file. Also, simplifies the deployment.